# How to exit the app on double back press?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a code to exit the app when double pressing the back button. I don't want to call super.onBackPressed(); since it takes me back to the first activity which is splash screen, and I don't want that, I want to exit the app on double pressing. Thank you.

This is my onBackPressed method:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

    if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else{


        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(a);
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);

    }

}
```

Comment: why is your splash activity still open ? if you found a way to finish the splash, then the rest of your code would work, right ?

Comment: Solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't call `finish()` before you start your second Activity from the first one, it will remain, so when you close your second one,
the program takes you back to the first one, which is not finished yet.

So call `finish()` after `startActivity()` in your first Activity

Answer (score 1):

1. Define two class level variables like
   private long TIME_DELAY = 2000;
   private long back_pressed;
2. on OnBackPressed() method, write below code.

   if (back_pressed + TIME_DELAY > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
   finish();
   super.onBackPressed();

   ```
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.press_back_again_to_exit,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

just use `finish()` after launching the intent to the next activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, NextActivity.class));

//Below will enable the app to exit if back is pressed
finish();
```